# How to change a variable's value from another script in a switch statement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, switch-statement

I am building a game in unity and I want the player to be able to buy permanent upgrades (it will stay until the end of the game).

I have this script on my `shopManager` gameObject:

```
public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int coins;

    //References
    public PlayerController playerCon;
    public HurtEnemy[] hurtEnms;
    public HurtPlayer[] hurtPlas;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerCon = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
        hurtEnms = FindObjectsOfType<HurtEnemy>(); //there are a few weapons that can hurt enemies
        hurtPlas = FindObjectsOfType<HurtPlayer>(); //there are a few enemies that can hurt the player
    }

    public void BuyItem(ShopItem item)
    {
        if (coins>=item.price)
        {
            coins -= item.price;
            ApplyChangesToPlayer(item);
        }
    }

    public void ApplyChangesToPlayer(ShopItem item)
    {
        switch (item.name)
        {
            case "Speed":
                playerCon.speed += 1f;
                break;
            case "Strength": //doing more damage
                foreach (var hurtEnm in hurtEnms)
                    hurtEnm.damage++;
                break;
            case "Reduced damage": //all enemies do less damage
                foreach (var hurtPla in hurtPlas)
                    hurtPla.damagePerHit--;
                break;
            case "Weapon": 
                playerCon.hasWeapon = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The boost is given only if I choose speed, but it does not work for the others.

The variables I am trying to get (`hasWeapon`, `damage` and `damagePerHit`) are public in the script in which they are defined:

```
public class HurtEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage;
}
```

```
public class HurtPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damagePerHit;
}
```

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public bool hasWeapon=false;
}
```

I don't understand why the speed boost works, while the others don't.

Comment: please show what `HurtEnemy.hasWeapon` actually is ( and the other two ones also, of course).

Comment: so are you trying to change another scripts varaible in a switch, or do you want the switch to allow for "all"? or are you asking how to apply "all" ...  your title and question dont seem to match

Comment: Sorry, my english is not that good so I have trouble explaining. I just want to change the variable's value based on the item's name (the one that the player bought).

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? Can you show how you rigged those to work?

Comment: When I run the game and try to buy speed boost, the player's speed increase, but when I try to buy any other thing nothing changes.

Comment: And may I ask what do you mean be rigging those to work?

Comment: How are you calling it? What debugging have you done. Given you use strings it only takes a space or typo and it wont work.